# copy file name and certain text string then place it into a specific part of all files in subdirectories

Tags: python, regex, unix, bioinformatics

I have many files in subdirectories eg. UCE-1…UCE-2000, which all contain the same two file types (a `.cfg` file and a `.phylip` file).

```
UCEs

UCE-13

partition_finder.cfg 

UCE-13.phylip
```

I need to modify the .cfg file in all of these UCE-1...UCE-2000 folders. Specifically, I need to copy the file name of the `.phylip` file `UCE-13.phylip` and place it in a specific section of text inside the `.cfg` file, for instance change

`alignment  = ;`

to

`alignment = UCE-13.phylip;`

A second modification I need to make is to copy a section of text always found in the .phylip file at the end of the first line preceded by a space and replace it in a specific location of the `.cfg` file.

Copy last set of numbers in 1st line of the `.phylip` file between the space and return

```
2 466\r
```

Then find replace it in .cfg

`All = 1-;`

to

`All = 1-466;`

The numbers very in length.

Any help with either of these problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the changes you tried. That would help in rectifing things!

Comment: find /directory -name \*.confg -exec sed -i "s/All = 1-;/All = 1-some_num;/g" {} \;
but am not sure how to get the “2 466\r” from the .phylip file and place it in the right way, sorry new to regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

start in “All-UCEs"
the info is all common to a subdir so
go to that dir first
get the phylip name
get the last field of the first row of the phylip file
stick them in the .cfg file
(use double quote to allow expansion of shell var in sed)
change back out of the dir

```
for dir in UCE-*; do
    cd ${dir}
    phylip="*.phylip"
    some_num=`awk 'NR==1{print $NF}' ${phylip}`
    sed -i "s/alignment  = ;/alignment  = ${phylip};/;\
        s/All = 1-;/All = 1-${some_num};" *.cfg
    cd ..
done
```

(untested)

Comment: sorry the file structure is this
“All-UCEs/UCE-1/ partition_finder.cfg uce-1.phylip    

I modified the script some as awk was not finding the .phylip file as well as for sed –i in mac,       

for dir in uce-*; do
    phylip="${dir}/*.phylip"
    some_num=`awk 'NR==1{print $NF}' ${phylip}`
    sed -i '' 's/alignment = ;/alignment = ${phylip};/' ${dir}/*.cfg 
    sed -i '' 's/All = 1-;/All = 1-${some_num};/' ${dir}/*.cfg 
done
       
Unfortunately it places the text “${phylip}” and “All = 1-${some_num};” instead of the values. 
Thanks again!

Comment: sorry being redundant with the ${dir} in two places, just cd there ant forget the rest. shell variables do not expand inside single quotes, change to double quotes